# What is the R to C++ syntax for vectors?

Tags: c++, c, vector, rcpp

I am an R and C programmer trying to use Rcpp to create an R (and C++) wrapper for a program written in C.  I'm not really familiar with C++.

Can someone help me understand the documentation on how to import an R object as a C++ vector?  (I'm specifically trying to import an R list that includes a mixture of int, double, and numeric lists.)

The Rcpp-introduction.pdf states:

> The reverse conversion from an R object to a C++ object is implemented by variations of 
>   the `Rcpp::as` template whose signature is:
>
> ```
> template <typename T> T as(SEXP x);
> ```
>
> It offers less sexibility and currently handles conversion of R objects into primitive types (e.g., `bool`, `int`, `std::string`, ...), STL vectors of primitive types (e.g.,
>   `std::vector<bool>`, `std::vector<double>`, ...) and arbitrary types that offer a constructor that takes a SEXP.

I am confused as to what this means, i.e. what gets filled in for "template", "typename T", and "T".  I've seen what appear to be lots of examples for the primitives, e.g.

```
int dx = Rcpp::as<int>(x);
```

but I don't understand how this syntax maps to the template documentation above, and (more importantly) don't understand how to generalize this to STL vectors.

Comment: Try `std::vector<int> v = Rcpp::as< std::vector<int> >(v);` etc.

Comment: You might find http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/ useful as an example of navigating an R list in Rcpp as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are making it too complicated.  An R vector just becomes a C++ vector "because that is what Rcpp does for you".

Here it is using `Rcpp::NumericVector`:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction('NumericVector ex1(NumericVector x) { return x + 2;}')
R> ex1(1:4)  # adds two
[1] 3 4 5 6
R>
```

This uses the fact that we defined `+` for our `NumericVector` types. You can also pass a `std::vector<double>` in and out, but need to add some operations which is often more than one statement so I didn't here...

So in short, keep reading the documentation and ask on rcpp-devel or here if you need help.

*Edit:* For completeness, the same with a STL vector

```
R> cppFunction('std::vector<double> ex2(std::vector<double> x) { \
                 for (size_t i=0; i<x.size(); i++) x[i] = x[i] + 2; return x;}')
R> ex2(1:4)
[1] 3 4 5 6
R>
```

Comment: I haven't tried compiling yet, but I think that Kerrek's comment clears up the thing that I needed clarified.

Ultimately my goal is to pass R lists to C/C++ code and use existing C code that is set up to handle C structs and arrays, so I need to know how to handle the data structures on the C/C++ end.